# Помогите исправить алгоритм поиска подстэка C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, стек

Необходимо проверить является ли стэк s2 подстэком s1 без изменения данных стэков. Я написала алгоритм, но на отдельных тестах, таких как в main алгоритм не работает. Он не работает так как стэк s2 меняется и дальше идет неправильная проверка, s2 сравнивается со стэком s1 не сначала, но я не знаю как это исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
template <typename T>
bool is_substack(stack<T>& s1, stack<T>& s2)
{
    if (s2.empty() || s1.empty())
        return false;
    if (s1.size() <= s2.size())
        return false;
    else
    {
        stack<T> temp1, temp2;
        T a, b;
            b = s2.top();
            s2.pop();
            temp2.push(b);
            a = s1.top();
            s1.pop();
            temp1.push(a);
        while (!s1.empty() && a != b)
        {
            a = s1.top();
            s1.pop();
            temp1.push(a);
        }
        if (s1.empty())
            return false;
        else
        {
            while (a == b && !s2.empty())
            {
                a = s1.top();
                s1.pop();
                temp1.push(a);
                b = s2.top();
                s2.pop();
                temp2.push(b);
            }
            if (s2.empty())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        while (!temp1.empty())
        {
            T a;
            a = temp1.top();
            temp1.pop();
            s1.push(a);
        }
        while (!temp2.empty())
        {
            T b;
            b = temp2.top();
            temp2.pop();
            s2.push(b);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    stack<int> s1;
    stack<int> s2;
    s1.push(1);
    s1.push(1);
    s1.push(1);
    s1.push(0);
    s1.push(1);

    s2.push(1);
    s2.push(1);
    s2.push(1);
    cout << is_substack(s1, s2) << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Обязательно со стеками надо? Другими структурами пользоваться можно?

Comment: Обязательно стэками и стэковыми операциями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
template <typename T>
bool is_substack(stack<T> s1, stack<T> s2)
{
    if (s2.empty()) return true; // Пустой стек - подстек любого
    if (s1.empty()) return false;
    if (s1.size() < s2.size()) return false;

    while (s1.size() >= s2.size())
    {
        stack<T> tmp;
        T b;
        b = s2.top();
        while(!s1.empty() && s1.top() != b) s1.pop();
        if (s1.size() < s2.size()) return false;
        for(;s1.size() >= s2.size();)
        {
            while(!s2.empty() && s1.top() == s2.top())
            {
                tmp.push(s2.top());
                s1.pop();
                s2.pop();
            }
            if (s2.empty()) return true;
            while(!tmp.empty())
            {
                s1.push(tmp.top());
                s2.push(tmp.top());
                tmp.pop();
            }
            s1.pop();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось